# Splitting a dataframe and properly naming the output objects in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have dataframe which I want to split into separate variables (which will exist in R's environment) based on one of the variables in my dataset (in this case `$variable`). I know that dumping variables into my global environment is not advisable but...

Here is what I tried:

```
# create a mock dataframe
library(tidyverse)
a <- 1:26
b <- LETTERS[1:26]
c <- 1:26
variable <- c("Newvariable1", "Newvariable1", "Newvariable1", "Newvariable1", "Newvariable1", "Newvariable1", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable5", "Newvariable5", "Newvariable5", "Newvariable5")


mockdataframe <- cbind(a,b,c, variable)
mockdataframe <- as_tibble(mockdataframe)

# split dataframe according to variable of choice
splitmockdataframe <- split(mockdataframe, mockdataframe$variable)

# create new objects based on variable
names(splitmockdataframe) <- c("Newvariable1", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable5")
list2env(splitmockdataframe, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

This works, but it is tedious to use when I have massive datasets with thousands of values to write out in the `c()` function.

I tried this below, but it doesn't correctly name each newly created object.

```
# use the same dataframe, but don't use split() function:

mockdataframe <- cbind(a,b,c, variable)
mockdataframe <- as_tibble(mockdataframe)

# create new R objects
names <- unique(mockdataframe$variable)
for(i in seq_along(names)) 
  assign(paste0(names, i), subset(mockdataframe, variable == names[i]))
```

How can I do what I want without having to type out all of the variable names?

Comment: But you don't have to run this step at all. `names(splitmockdataframe) <- c("Newvariable1", "Newvariable2", "Newvariable3", "Newvariable4", "Newvariable5")`. `splitmockdataframe` already is a named list so if you remove that line from your code it will still work. Did you try that?

Comment: @RonakShah That did work! Thank you so much for your answer, I'm embarrassed that I didn't catch that. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this(?):

```
> variable <- sort(rep(paste0("NewVariable",1:4),4))
> 
> variable
 [1] "NewVariable1" "NewVariable1" "NewVariable1" "NewVariable1" "NewVariable2" "NewVariable2" "NewVariable2" "NewVariable2"
 [9] "NewVariable3" "NewVariable3" "NewVariable3" "NewVariable3" "NewVariable4" "NewVariable4" "NewVariable4" "NewVariable4"
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that isn't what I want. I would like every new data frame or object created to have the appropriate name like I had in the fist chunk of code above. But thank you again!